# How do you set up an object oriented jsonrpc Mojolicious application?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to set up a jsonrpc application using Mojo.  I built some controllers
and related modules using REST but then decided I needed to use JSONRPC.

Using the following code from [http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::JsonRpcDispatcher](http://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aJsonRpcDispatcher)

```
# lib/your-application.pm

use base 'Mojolicious';
use MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service;

sub startup {
    my $self = shift;
    my $svc = MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service->new;

    $svc->register(
        'sum',
        sub {
            my @params = @_;
            my $sum = 0;
            $sum += $_ for @params;
            return $sum;
        }
    );

    $self->plugin(
        'json_rpc_dispatcher',
        services => {
           '/jsonrpc' => $svc
        }
    );
```

I was able to replicate one of my Controller => Model relationships where the controller
was ported to this format in one file.

I'd like to set it up so that the application file basically can load the each of the files
as a service similar to what this page displays [http://metacpan.org/pod/MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service](http://metacpan.org/pod/MojoX%3a%3aJSON%3a%3aRPC%3a%3aService)

```
$svc->register(
    'sum',
    sub {
        my @params = @_;
        my $sum    = 0;
        $sum += $_ for @params;
        return $sum;
    }
);
```

In other words, what I'm envisioning is reworking each controller to act similar to 
the snippet above but have them all loaded in the application module. Like this:

```
## Then in Mojolicious application
$self->plugin(
    'json_rpc_dispatcher',
    services => {
        '/jsonrpc'  => $svc,
    }
);
```

Is it possible to create a file with functions set up like the code above and then load
them as servers in the application module?   MojoX::JSON::RPC::Service appears to offer that. I've been unable to get it to work.

Comment: I got this to work to a certain degree.  But the first object in @_ is my controller containing only _rpcs => { method_name => { with_svc_obj => 1, method => sub { DUMMY } } }.  I'm unsure what to do with it.